# Displaying custom posts in categories

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have created a custom post type "brochures" which i am currently displaying with the code below (using ACF to display the brochure file).
At the moment this displays all the brochures individually.

I have set up a custom taxonomy for this post type called "brochure_categories" so that i can categories the brochures into separate folders like the below.

**Brochure Category 1**
Brochure 1
Brochure 2

**Brochure Category 2**
Brochure 3
Brochure 4

**Brochure Category 3**
Brochure 5
Brochure 6

Rather displaying all the posts (like im doing with the code below), i want to display all of the brochure categories, and when a category is clicked it then displays the posts within that category.

How am i able to achieve this?

```
<ul class="brochures">
    <?php 
  $temp = $wp_query; 
  $wp_query = null; 
  $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
  $wp_query->query('showposts=18&orderby=title&order=ASC&post_type=brochures'.'&paged='.$paged); 

  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
?>

  <li><a target="_blank" href="<?php the_field('brochure_file'); ?>"><img src="<?php the_field('brochure_logo'); ?>"><h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3><h4>Click to view</h4></a>
            </li>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<nav class="nextPrev">
    <div class="prev"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?></div>
    <div class="next"><?php next_posts_link('Next &raquo;') ?></div>
</nav>

<?php 
  $wp_query = null; 
  $wp_query = $temp;  // Reset
?>

</ul>
```

Comment: If you've set up a custom taxonomy, why not just use the native term archives, and the `taxonomy-{taxonomy-name}.php` template - no need for custom querying here.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all the **terms** attached to your taxonomy "brochure_categories", you can use `get_terms()` function. More info [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/).

Once you've got your terms, you can traverse them and query your custom posts with:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type'             => 'brochures',
  'brochure_categories'   => $current_category,
  'posts_per_page'        => -1,
  'order'                 => 'ASC',
  'orderby'               => 'title',
) );
```

You can now display them, by category, as it suits you.

Is it ok for you ?

Answer (score 0):

```
try This Code Change taxonomy name which you are using 

/**post type name: brochures **/
/** taxonomy name: brochures-cat **/
<?php 
  $custom_terms = get_terms('brochures-cat');
  foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
   wp_reset_query();
   $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'brochures',
      'tax_query' => array(
          array(
           'taxonomy' => 'brochures-cat',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
          ),
         ),
      );
   $loop = new WP_Query($args);
   if($loop->have_posts()) {
    echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';
    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br />';
    endwhile;
   }
  }
    ?>
```